# Do I need a setter for two-way binding?

Tags: angular, binding, getter-setter

I've created a checkbox with two-way binding to a getter. I don't have a setter because the getter will return a result of filtering of a list.

Locally this solution works fine but after deployment I get the following error "Cannot set property myProperty of [object Object] which has only a getter at Object.handleEvent"

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="myId" [(ngModel)]="myProperty" (change)="toggleSelection($event)"/>

public get myProperty(): boolean {
        return this.list.every(function(item: any) {
            return item.selected == true;
        });
    }

toggleSelection(event) {
        this.list.forEach(h => (h.selected = event.target.checked));
    }
```

I try to understand what is going on. When I create a setter and remove the change event it will work after deployment.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="myId"[(ngModel)]="myProperty""/>

    public set myProperty(checked: boolean) { 
        this.list.forEach(h => (h.selected = checked));
    }
    public get myProperty(): boolean {
        return this.list.every(function(item: any) {
            return item.selected == true;
        });
    }
```

Now I want to understand why the first implementation works locally.
Locally I don't need a setter but after deployment (a build) it needs a setter.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, two ways binding means:

- The variable changes the HTML element (this is the **get** part of the binding).
- The HTML element changes the variable (this is the **set** part of the binding).

Therefore the right using in Angular for two ways binding is when you need to get & set.
In my opinion, in your case you should use the option of one-way binding - variable that changes the HTML, like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="myId"
       [checked]="myProperty" (change)="toggleSelection($event)"/>

public get myProperty(): boolean {
    return this.list.every(function(item: any) {
        return item.selected == true;
    });
}

toggleSelection(event) {
    this.list.forEach(h => (h.selected = event.target.checked));
}
```

This is the right way in the concept of Angular.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the change event in my example (<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="myId" [(ngModel)]="myProperty" (change)="toggleSelection($event)"/> ). I've edited my original post. So I need two way binding.In the toggleSelection the list gets updated.

Comment: Do you also know why this works locally and not after build (deployment)?

Comment: @M S I found a solution, see updated post. Now I only want to know why it didn't worked with my original implementation.